# doubt regarding a concept of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $L$ be a set which has a property if an element $p$ and an element $q$ belong to the set then $p\cdot q$ also belongs to the set. My doubt is then that will $p^2$ belong to the set or not?

Comment: If $p$ belongs to the set and $p$ also belongs (Does it?) to he set then $p\cdot p$ belongs to the set.

Comment: This is completely ambiguous, and thus has little meaning.

Comment: @zoli if the definition bothered to qualify $p,q$ then I could see an afirmitive result about "p.p". Unless I miss something.

Comment: Consider the sets like $\{p, q, p.q\}$ then it is qualified by the question but $p^2$ or $p.p$ not in it.

Comment: There is qualification. If $p$ and $q$ are contained then $p\cdot q$ is contained. It follows that if $p$ is contained then  $p$ is contaioned, as well. So $p\cdot q$ is contained. The question remains: Do we consider the operation $p\cdot p$ equivalent to the operation $p^2$? (May be this is what you miss.

Comment: Obv $p=p, q=q$ but anything more needs to be stated.

Comment: The OP never said it was a set of integers or numbers at all, it would just have to be some set with a multiplication defined. It could even be just the set {0}, {1}, or {0,1} and still not be infinite. But if it were a subset of the naturals containing something other than 0 or 1 then yes, the set would be at least countably infinite.

Comment: ah, you are totally right @Grant, thanks for pointing it (I deleted my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

If $\forall p,q \in L,\ p\cdot q \in L $, then when an element $a$ (let's use $a $ instead of $p $ since I think that is where your confusion arises), is in $L $, we know from substitution into our assumption that since $a,a\in L, a\cdot a=a^2\in L $. The $q $ does not have to be different from the $p $, they are just names that could potentially belong to the same object.